# in Xcode 6, scale value from image diff with value in UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Now i develop an app that all user drag, rotate and scale image inside uiview. but when i want to save image view data like rotate value and scale value. i found scale value from [[img.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue] diff with scale that i found. the scale value is like below.

-(void)scale:(id)sender {

```
if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    _lastScale = 1.0;
}

CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (_lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

//CGFloat scale = 1.0 + ([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale] - _lastScale);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[self setTransform:newTransform];

_lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];

CGFloat size = [[self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

self.saveScale = _lastScale;

NSLog(@"Scale %f %f",_lastScale, size);
```

}

so the save scale value is diff with [[img.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"].

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

You need to add Delegate

```
@interface MyClass : MySuperClass <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set up the image view
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
    [imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 120.0)];
    [imageView setCenter:self.view.center];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // <--- This is very important

    // create and configure the pinch gesture
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGestureDetected:)];
    [pinchGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];

    // create and configure the rotation gesture
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGestureRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationGestureDetected:)];
    [rotationGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationGestureRecognizer];


    [self.view addSubview:imageView]; // add the image view as a subview of the view controllers view
}
```

add this two methods

```
- (void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGFloat scale = [recognizer scale];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, scale, scale)];
        [recognizer setScale:1.0];
    }
}

- (void)rotationGestureDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGFloat rotation = [recognizer rotation];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, rotation)];
        [recognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}
```

after add this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ur coding. Do you know how to limit pan gesture ? mean image only can move inside particular view.

Comment: i use this method CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.tablePlanFloor];
    
    CGRect boundsRect = self.tablePlanFloor.bounds;
    
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(boundsRect, point)) {
        img.center = point;
    }

Comment: you need to more conditions for this.

Comment: can provide some example ?

Answer (score 3):

Declare Variable -> CGFloat currentScale;

```
- (void) handlePinches:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)paramSender{

    if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        currentScale = paramSender.scale;
    } else if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan &&
               self.currentScale != 0.0f){
        paramSender.scale = currentScale;
    }

    if (paramSender.scale != NAN &&
        paramSender.scale != 0.0){
        paramSender.view.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeScale(paramSender.scale,
                                   paramSender.scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks your help.  But after adding this code my my picture become cannot rotate. is it effect it ?

Comment: plz exp. how many operation to perform on your picture. so i can give you that all code.

Comment: the operation to perform on my image is just scale and rotate. Thanks Your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle also pangesture using this method.
add pan gesture in to image.

```
 self.panResizeGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGestures:)];
    imgPatSelect.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imgPatSelect addGestureRecognizer:self.panResizeGesture];
```

add this method to handle pan.

```
- (void) handlePanGestures:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
 CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGRect recognizerFrame = recognizer.view.frame;
    recognizerFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
    recognizerFrame.origin.y += translation.y;

    // Check if UIImageView is completely inside its superView
    if (CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, recognizerFrame)) {
        recognizer.view.frame = recognizerFrame;
    }
    // Else check if UIImageView is vertically and/or horizontally outside of its
    // superView. If yes, then set UImageView's frame accordingly.
    // This is required so that when user pans rapidly then it provides smooth translation.
    else {
        // Check vertically
        if (recognizerFrame.origin.y < self.view.bounds.origin.y) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.y = 0;
        }
        else if (recognizerFrame.origin.y + recognizerFrame.size.height > self.view.bounds.size.height) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - recognizerFrame.size.height;
        }

        // Check horizantally
        if (recognizerFrame.origin.x < self.view.bounds.origin.x) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.x = 0;
        }
        else if (recognizerFrame.origin.x + recognizerFrame.size.width > self.view.bounds.size.width) {
            recognizerFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.width - recognizerFrame.size.width;
        }
    }

    // Reset translation so that on next pan recognition
    // we get correct translation value
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

Comment: Thanks u, you save my time. Thanks